# Multiply each element in array by all other elements in same array

Tags: ruby, arrays, enums

I am trying to create a times table in Ruby in which an integer is given and the output is a times table for that integer.

EXAMPLE: `times_table(5)`

results in:

```
1   2   3   4   5
2   4   6   8  10   
3   6   9  12  15   
4   8  12  16  20   
5  10  15  20  25
```

So far I have:

```
def times_table(rows)
  table_array = (1..rows).to_a

  table_array.each do |i|

end

times_table(5)
```

With table_array, I can get `[1,2,3,4,5]`, but I need to have the result be `1 * 2 , 1 * 3, 1 *  4, 1 * 5, 2 * 1, 2 * 2, 2 * 3` etc. Basically, I need the first element to multiple itself with all other elements in the array and then move on to the next element. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would do as below :

```
def times_table(rows)
  table_rng = (1..rows)
  table_rng.each do |i|
    puts table_rng.map{|e| e*i }.join(" ")
  end
end

times_table(5)
# >> 1 2 3 4 5
# >> 2 4 6 8 10
# >> 3 6 9 12 15
# >> 4 8 12 16 20
# >> 5 10 15 20 25
```

**update( A great suggestion from  Cary Swoveland)**

```
def times_table(rows)
  fmt = "%#{(rows*rows).to_s.size}d"
  table_rng = (1..rows)
  table_rng.each do |i|
    puts table_rng.map{|e| fmt % (e*i) }.join(' ')
  end
end

times_table(5)
# >>  1  2  3  4  5
# >>  2  4  6  8 10
# >>  3  6  9 12 15
# >>  4  8 12 16 20
# >>  5 10 15 20 25
```

Comment: `to_a` can be removed.

Comment: @steenslag Thanks for the pointer.. It came due to copy-paste :)

Comment: Maybe neaten a bit: `width = (rows*rows).to_s.size`, then `puts table_rng.map{|e| "%#{width}d" % (e*i) }.join(' ')`.  I mention this in part because I noticed that without the parentheses, the second expression evaluates as `("%#{width}d" % e)*i`, something I thought I might pass on.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Awesome! I just didn't think about the formatting!! I liked your approach and would appreciate your help for improving my answer.

Comment: Slight improvement to use `fmt` rather than `width` as per an answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, I would prefer using `Matrix` in that use-case.

The relation being, you have to generate **n*n** matrix, where each cell has relation `(c+1) * (r+1)` where, `c` denotes *column-number* and `r` denotes *row-number* (considering, 0 indexed matrix)

```
require 'matrix'
def times_table(n)
  Matrix.build(n, n) { |r, c| (c+1)*(r+1) }
end

times_table(5)
#=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]
times_table(5).to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
 [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
 [4, 8, 12, 16, 20],
 [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way that requires ActiveSupport:

```
def times_table(n)
  [*1..n].product([*1..n]).map { |arr| arr.reduce(:*) }.in_groups(n)  
end
```

So, for example, `times_table(5)` would return

```
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
   [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
   [4, 8, 12, 16, 20],
   [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]
```

You could pretty print it to your taste from there.

**Update**: As Cary points out, `in_groups` is part of ActiveSupport. Here's the above code slightly amended so that it should work with standard Ruby:

```
def times_table(n)
  [*1..n].product([*1..n]).map { |arr| arr.reduce(:*) }.each_slice(n).to_a  
end
```

You could also do this:

```
def times_table(n)
  Array.new(n) { |x| Array.new(n) { |y| (x+1)*(y+1) } }
end
```

Comment: Should `in_groups` be unfamiliar (as it was to me), it's part of ActiveSupport.  You might want to ditch "..for better or worse" in this and future answers.  It's like saying, "you probably won't like this, but.."

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism, Cary. Trying to get the hang of answering questions confidently on Stack Overflow. By 'for better or for worse' I meant this is compact code that works, but likely isn't the most efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: I think providing alternative solutions is worthwhile, even in situations where you think a solution presented by someone else is superior, as it may give the reader ideas that can be applied to other problems in future.  In such situations you might say something like, "Here is alternative approach, though I prefer the use of XXX in this situation."

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
def times_table(rows, spaces=1)
  fmt = "%#{(rows*rows).to_s.size}d"
  (1..rows).each {|i| \
    puts (i..i*rows).step(i).map {|j| fmt % j}.join(' '*spaces)}
end

times_table(5,2)

1   2   3   4   5
2   4   6   8  10
3   6   9  12  15
4   8  12  16  20
5  10  15  20  25
```

Comment: I mean `[*1..rows].each_index.{..}`